# Is it possible to free a char * allocated with a calloc"

Tags: c, string, free, calloc

I would like to know if it's possible to free a `char *` (string) allocated with `calloc` but several times.

```
char * signal;  

for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)  {   
   signal = (char*) calloc(n, sizeof(char));
   if (a = true) {
      signal[i] = 1;
   }

   /* do stuff */

   free(signal); /* error here : double free or corruption */   
}
```

Why do I get the error on the `free()`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would try to free it more than one time? You can do it only once.

Comment: At a guess the problem isn't with the code you've shown us, but lies within the "do stuff" part

Comment: Beware the assignment in the conditional: `if (a = true)` is like `if ((a = true) != 0)`!

Comment: `if(a = true)`: you probably meant `if(a == true)` (since the former is always true by assignment).

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: Does the code include "`<stdlib.h>`"? What happens if you remove the useless cast to `calloc()`?

Comment: The code you have shown looks okay from a memory-management perspective (as Valgrind will likely tell you), as each time around the loop you allocate and free one block of memory.  Unless the `/* do stuff */` modifies the value of `signal` to point somewhere else, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> would like to know if it's possible to free a char * (string) allocated with calloc but several times.

Short answer: No

Long answer: One call to [`malloc()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.4), [`calloc()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.2), [`realloc(NULL, ...)`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5)<sup>(*1)</sup> allows (requires, to not leak memory) *exactly one* call to [`free()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3) passing the value to the latter as returned by one of the former.

So, if passing an already `free()`ed address to `free()` and assuming it had not been returned by another allocation after the previous call to `free()`, then the code invokes undefined behaviour, anything can happen from then on.

---

<sup>(*1)</sup> Notes on `realloc()`:

- Successive calls to `realloc()` not passing `NULL` do not increment the sum of necessary calls to `free()`. In other words

  ```
  char * p = malloc(42);
  p = realloc(43);
  ```

  does require only *one* call to `free()`

  ```
  free(p);
  ```
- Passing `NULL` to `realloc()` makes `realloc()` count like a call to `malloc()`.

  Doing

  ```
  char * p = realloc(NULL, 42);
  ```

  Is the same as doing

  ```
  char * p = malloc(42);
  ```

Comment: @TobySpeight: For which reason did you change the order of the last to code lines?

Comment: To match the sense of the description - (this call to realloc) should be counted like (this call to malloc).  That's the usual form in English, and I think that it makes more logical sense that way around.  If you disagree, edit it back, and I won't object!

Comment: @TobySpeight: Just had a look at your profile. Scotsmen (also, more or less ;-)) speak English, don't they? So I take you as native speaker, and stick to your advice. :-)

Comment: Actually, I moved here from England about 10 years ago, so you can definitely call me a native speaker.  Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Internally both [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) should do the same thing to allocate memory (just as [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) does). The only difference being a call to [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) in [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc). So yes memory you allocate with [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) must be passed to [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) if you want to avoid a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one C function used to free the dynamically-allocated memory. That function is [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) and it can, should and must be used to release any block of memory allocated with [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), [`calloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) or [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

The code you posted seems ok. If you get memory corruption it is from the code you didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code

1. cleanly compiles
2. cleanly links
3. does not produce any run time problem

and now the code

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // calloc(), free()

int main( void )
{
    char * signal;
    size_t n = 10;
    int a = 1;

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
       signal = calloc(n, sizeof(char));
       if (a)
       {
          signal[i] = 1;
       }

       /* do stuff */

       free(signal); /* error here : double free or corruption */
    }
}
```

This indicates the problem your experiencing is due to something in the `do stuff` area.

One thing I would look at is: check that any 'index' into `signal` never goes below 0 and never exceeds `n-1` as either error will corrupt the heap.  A corrupted heap will (usually) cause a call to `free()` to fail.

Also check that the contents of the pointer `signal` is never changed by the `do stuff` as that will also result in a call to `free()` to fail.